# Why is writing to a specific csv not working in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a python program that runs a certain experiment on an artificial deck of cards. I want to save average the number of trials it took to get a certain pattern to the csv file, but I having trouble getting the program to write to a specific cvs file who's directory I've specified. The relevant code is shown below:

```py
row = [str(n), str(limit), str(np.mean(trial_time_list)), str(max(trial_time_list)), str(np.std(trial_time_list))]
with open("D:\Documents\python projects\\results.csv", "a") as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerow(row)

csvFile.close()
```

The code runs without any errors, but when I check the csv files, no new data is written onto it. Is it because I'm not running IDLE with admin permissions?

Comment: Because you're not escaping your backslashes.  Voting to close as off-topic -> typo.

Comment: As an aside. You don't need the `close` if you are using `with`. You could also make your first line more readable like `row = [str(x) for x in (n, limit, np.mean(trial_time_list), max(trial_time_list), np.std(trial_time_list)]`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 If an escape sequence with backslash isn't valid, it is interpreted just as backslash + character. `\D` and `\p` aren't valid so this is ok here. A `\r` would be valid so the extra backslash is necessary: `\\r`. But of course it isn't a good idea to write it that way.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Huh, TIL.  I'm unable to repro their issue either way without the data they're feeding.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and use `os.path.join` to make your file names...

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I think I get what you mean by escaping, but I tried running it as `open("D:\\Documents\\results.csv", "a")` (I hope I formatted that right) while moving the csv and it still didn't work. I'm also getting a weird glitch where the code won't save to a new directory, I hit save as on IDEL and it saves, but it doesn't show up in the directory

Comment: @vatgas Did you validate the folder path exists?

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to reproduce your issue so I suspect there's something wrong with your environment.  I suggest enforcing your assumptions:

```
import csv
import os
import numpy as np

# something about n, limit, and trial_time_list

row = [str(x) for x in (n, limit, np.mean(trial_time_list), max(trial_time_list), np.std(trial_time_list)]

path = r'D:\Documents\python projects'
os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)
file = os.path.join(path, 'results.csv')
with open(file, 'a', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thank you! I got it working. The only thing is, I have to make it run through IDLE to make it work. Is there any reason why this wouldn't work when I run it through Spyder?